Bash printf float formatting became nonsensical and random
Bash printf floating number formatting (with %f or %g) is suddenly completely wrong, and changing all the time.
An example output:
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ printf '%g\n' 1
1.20739e+3531
$ printf '%g\n' 1
4.50784e-4778
$ printf '%g\n' 1
1.20739e+3531
$ printf '%g\n' 1
-2.71289e-809
$ printf '%g\n' 1
1.3505e+3136
$ printf '%g\n' 1
7.19546e+2880
$ printf '%f\n' 1
0.000000
$ printf '%f\n' 1
-19222373783767455764509969957314767706032565305205751517976389011586356910287283735873496366975075385910809025031233228909443235485943598697862160225065543796566324326303010027986380740507313362109478389280032720809755605977575591712977484833714421549464179548312816619669691695969675768618124142786377660052446990574866227828104911221712770547544994592495621702453486060768120985842267603349960735550433657827156688542311891238932963870595675569407105652838611000368894193915118759451716250477855842495787217908770520219596001805968923516834815448319714521179606192054239712352794281273655344703644255690153172028191401140768961585354430400117766273628103129509500449952562778071128862373050266582261154261590345666202936676378315868263637718127652344391988248019089245237502067305800855582602326233046151999935749805709388443164385685796904118233897433899895164143403147924128628840995216653448904704.000000
$ printf '%f\n' 1
-1535939692251970798780814048195400843655654544941633379309930935432267368465724365567117453392273362651582982424721184431169329486749020702578930669204206705946793193732917405530938783202632819503328225917797530425669645856818642162664722510713747202433401571296943178862058175872487260754269792220244257605097737000140353828109440097622967061126831273879953063844519410176251996107980841451192710472925184.000000
$ printf '%f\n' 1
-559936185544451048996856397218869061556420299014564433770484452018186365447891968084773838558135844864.000000

It is bash builtin that is being used, as I can see when typing command -v printf.
alias printf says "not found". I have the binaries at /bin/printf and /usr/bin/printf that behave normally. Awk and Python equivalent commands behave normally. Interestingly, when using sh, it's fine too.
I am on Debian testing, and I tried to apt upgrade and reboot but the bug persists.
Bash version is GNU bash, version 5.2.32(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). I tried apt reinstall bash without success. Yesterday for another reason I did a apt-get dist-upgrade.
What have I done?! It's wild.
[EDIT: additional debugging below]

Run a Memtest86+ for 12 passes, detected no error.
recompiled Bash 5.2.32 from GNU, it has the problem.
tried as another user.
This bug has been reported here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1078556. I guess I am going to continue this topic with the Debian bug report system.

Here is the content of /etc/apt/sources.list:
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free non-free-firmware contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security testing-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware contrib

and I also have /etc/apt/preferences.d/security as suggested in Best practices for Testing users:
Package: src:chromium src:firefox src:firefox-esr src:linux src:linux-signed-amd64
Explanation: these packages are always security updates updated in unstable first
Pin: release a=/^(unstable|unstable-debug|buildd-unstable|buildd-unstable-debug)$/
Pin-Priority: 980


Did the dist-upgrade replace/update libraries on which bash depends? Have you tried a new instance of bash since? I hesitate to suggest it, but what about a reboot

FWIW I unpacked bash_5.2.32-1+b1_amd64.deb locally on an Ubuntu 24.04 box, and printf '%f\n' 1 mostly gives me nan (occasionally -nan). OTOH the same bash version built from source on the same system seems to behave as expected.

"I am on Debian testing" - that's the reason. "Testing" flavors of most distros usually have the latest versions of packages, but which are not guaranteed to perform as expected.

@ChrisDavies no it does not seem so. My Bash package only depends on base-files and debianutils, and predepends on libc6 and libtinfo6, for which I have a compatible version.

At this point, I will try to install bash from source to double check, or reinstall Debian and stay on 'stable'. I could alternatively try to upgrade to 'unstable'?

@steeldriver Ah! I also observe nan!

@StéphaneChazelas Seems like this bug has been reported: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1078556
Not sure why, but I compiled previous versions of Bash (down to 5.2-rc4) and they also have the bug (does it come from a library then?). Failed to compile Bash 4.4 though.

Weird behaviour. I can't reproduce under gdb, I can under ltrace or ltrace -e '*@*' the latter showing __printf_chk behaving erratically, so could be a libc bug. I can't reproduce with any other shell or printf implementation or gawk's printf.

It is a bash bug. Looks like it was fixed upstreams but only on devel branch, no 5.2 patch yet AFAICT. See also https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2024-08/msg00111.html

@StéphaneChazelas So as user now, I need to either reinstall 'stable' or compile the latest upstream Bash?

Or apply patch on the package or wait for the fix to land in Debian. (or use zsh instead :-)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Effectively, bash 5.2 introduced a bug where on systems where strtold() is deemed broken and printf uses doubles instead of long doubles for its floating point as a result, it still ends up calling printf() with %Lf as the format. That particular bug was fixed on the devel branch, so will be included in 5.3, but not in the 5.2 branch (or rather, no official patch has been released yet, bash doesn't actually really use git).
Now, that should only have affected systems with a "broken" strtold().
The check for a broken strtold() which was added in 3.0 20 years ago, mentions HP/UX where according to the gnulib manual in some versions strtold() returned a struct instead of long double.
But that check itself was broken, it checked that a C file with:
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { long double r; char *foo, bar; r = strtold(foo, &bar); }

Compiled OK (which it wouldn't on HP/UX because of the type of the returned value), but it's calling strtold() with parameters of the wrong type, the second is a char* instead of a char**.
They're both pointers, so you used to get away with it with older compilers, but gcc 14 became stricter, in that -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types became enabled by default.
So the result is that with gcc 14, that check fails and strtold() is deemed broken even on systems where it's not, which causes to hit that other bug.
And even with the other bug fixed, that means printf reverts to doubles and ends up losing precision.
That bug was also (silently) fixed on the devel branch much earlier, but not on 5.2.x either yet.
A work around for now is to either apply those two fixes (both included in that message) and recompile the package, or compile it with gcc 13 or earlier.

Seems like I stumbled on a bug affecting Bash 5.2: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1078556
As indicated by @StéphaneChazelas, a fix has been made upstream.
At the moment I need to either use a correct version or apply this patch.

Upstream patch on devel branch is essentially the same. The commit log is misleading though. strotold() is not broken on Debian, it's the test that bash's configure does that is broken (another bug).

and looks like it has been broken since 3.0; it was apparently trying to cover for HP/UX whose strtold used to return a struct, but it's calling strtold with parameters of the wrong type (char bar should have been char *bar), that used to cause only a warning, but with newer gcc, that's an error, so strtold is deemed broken, on any system.

(an error since gcc 14)

IOW, building with gcc 13 or earlier would also work around the bug and avoid printf working with double instead of long double. Or you'd need to also apply that patch. Note that you also need your build system to have a en_US.UTF-8 locale available or some configure tests won't work properly.

So correcting my comment above, that patch and that is essentially the same as the one on the mailling list that you link is (should be) really only relevant to systems with broken strtold() (which you likely won't find these days), the more important patch to apply is that latter one to fix the build system.
